# "No module named tensorflow" after pip install in Anaconda Environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I just started to learn how to use Anaconda to manage packages. I am trying to install tensorflow in conda environment. So first of all, I create an environment by:

```
conda create -n tensorflow
```

Then, I source it by:

```
source activate tensorflow
```

I can see my prompt changed so I think it is going right.

I notice that it seems that the tensorflow environment is copying from ~/anaconda2/lib/ where I do have my root version python2.7 and tensorflow0.12.0

I installed a new version Python in tensorflow environment by:

```
conda install python=3.5
```

Then, I follow the steps to install tensorflow by:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade TF_PYTHON_URL
```

However, when I do conda list, I can only see Python3.5 but not tensorflow1.0. I also failed to import tensorflow when I am in Python.

So I have two questions that really confuse me.

1. Why does the pip installed tensorflow not show up when I do conda list?
2. Although I conda install python=3.5 and I can see it from conda list, I am not using python 3.5 when I enter Python directly. It seems still using Python2.7, which comes from my root environment.

I appreciate any tutorial on how anaconda works.

Comment: what OS are you using?  Do you see tensorflow with `pip list` ?

Comment: The anaconda documentation is pretty clear about all this.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If you have something helpful to say, why don't you just say it?

Comment: I pointed op to the root of all anaconda tutorials. Why are you getting offended on someone else's behalf?

Comment: @MadPhysicist RTFM is helpful if you add a link/section.  Otherwise don't even waste the keystrokes.

Comment: That's fair I suppose. OP should be qualified to type "anaconda documentation" Into Google without my help, but yet here we all are...

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Yes, I can see if I do pip list within the conda environment.

Comment: @Mad Physicist I think I follow the documentation where it says I can see the pip-installed packages from conda list. However, it does not show up.

Comment: @Wei `python --version` should tell you what version is called from `python`.  If you activated your tensorflow environment, it should be from within a tensorflow env folder.  Alternatively, you can navigate to the folder given by `which python` and use `ls -l python`; 'python' is usually a symbolic link that points to a specific version, e.g. 3.5.

Comment: @ ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird I guess your answer sort of solve the puzzle. So if I create an environment without explicitly setting a Python version, then the Python version would be the same as the root unless I do aliases python=/path/to/new/python/. It means conda install python=3.5 within the environment does not necessarily mean I am using the installed python.

Comment: @Wei use @user (no space) and they will get notified of your messages.  Re your last message: no.  I mean installing a new environment should create new executables (e.g. `python`) which points to, e.g., `python2.7` both in the same conda env folder typically.  I would suggest reinstalling anaconda, making sure to follow the doc precisely.  To create a new environment, I would prefer: `conda create -n tensorflow anaconda` which creates a full anaconda distribution in your virtual env.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `pip install` is installing into the global environment instead of 
`tensorflow`. Why don't you try installing by specifying the path? For example `pip install --target $HOME/anaconda3/tensorflow tensorflow`(Where the first `tensorflow` is your environment and the second is the actual package).

---

I just saw the last two questions. So you actually see the tensorflow you installed with pip? I am confused now. Type `which pip` to see if it is running from the `tensorflow` environment or the global. You could also try `source deactivate` before `source activate tensorflow` just to make sure that you are not using a different environment, then run `which python`. It *should* show your new environment.

Comment: I edited my question 1 since I missed the word "not". So I tried which pip and which python. It says:/home/wei/anaconda2/bin/pip and /home/wei/anaconda2/bin/python. My question is why does pip-installed tensorflow not show up in conda list and how do I use my conda-installed python within the environment?

Comment: @Wei then Anaconda is using your global path instead of the newly created environment. Does `tensorflow` show up when you do `conda list`  without doing `source activate` first? I mean, does the new version show up when you use your normal anaconda? I'm not on my computer right now, but I'll look into it when I get home.

Comment: @Wei: be sure to use these commands after activating your environment, e.g. `source activate tensorflow` - otherwise the root python/pip executables are called (as you observed).

Comment: @ Armando H. By saying "normal anaconda", did you mean at root environment? If so, yes, it shows up when I do 'conda list' wihtout sourcing any environment. And it shows as pip-installed, which is correct. I guess now the question turns out to be why Anaconda is not using newly created environment path.

Comment: @ ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird I actually did source activate tensorflow. The question is within the tensorflow environment, after pip-installing tensorflow1.3.0, I couldn't find it when I do conda list. Thus, I got "No module named tensorflow" error when I import it.

Comment: @Wei, yeah, I thought that was the issue. Deactivating all environments and then activating the tensorflow environment did not work, right? Can you run python directly from a path?

Comment: @ArmandoH. No, it does not show up in conda list within an environment. Rather, if I install tensorflow by pip within the environment, it shows up at /home/wei/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages, which confuses me since I thought it is supposed to show up in conda list.

Comment: @Wei ohhhhhhhhhh! I get it now, then it must be a pip problem rather than a conda problem. Have you tried reading the pip documentation?

Comment: @ArmandoH. Do you mean to use pip install --target=path/to/install/ package_name?

Comment: @Wei, yes, that was the solution I proposed, but I believe that did not work for you, right? If that's the case you might want to read the `pip` documentation. I'll check it out when I get in front of my computer.

Comment: @ArmandoH. In that case, I have to let python know the new path so that import can work. Actually, I notice that there two version of pip, root-pip and env-pip. That is, we should install tensorflow package using the conda-installed pip instead of the other since package will be installed in where the pip is installed. If I use conda installed pip to install tensorflow, it seems I can import it successfully. However, I cannot still see it from conda list, which does not match what the documentation says.

Comment: @Wei, I have some bad news. I still cannot replicate the problem. I still think it is a `pip` problem though. See, this is a workaround rather than a solution, but you could install a dedicated anaconda in a different path and run its python directly from the command prompt. For example, you install anaconda into `~/anaconda-tensorflow/` and then you run its python by opening the terminal and running `/anaconda-tensorflow/bin/python`. That should let you work with `tensorflow` and `pip` if you install them there. But as I said, it is a workaround and not a real solution.

Comment: @ArmandoH.I really appreciate your trying. I think I understand what you meant. I am also trying something now. I found out that yes, it is sort of a pip problem. I have to make sure I use the pip that is stored in anaconda folder to install other packages. So I force search path for Python and Pip to be in the anaconda folder. It seems to solve the issue. I am still testing if it will fail in some other scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create an environment using a specific version of Python (rather than the system default), you can do for example:

`conda create --name myCoolEnv python=3.5`

and then activate with

`source activate myCoolEnv`

You can read more about Anaconda environments [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I tried what you said. It does switch to the designated Python version. However, my question is that if I install a new Python after I created an environment, do I have to use "aliases python=/path/to/new/python/" to switch it?